# Quais são as regras de uso do Chat?

Tags: debate, comportamento, chat

Levando em consideração que nosso site já possui uma lista com algumas regras para uso do mesmo, gostaria de saber se ao entrarmos no chat, por se aumentar o escopo, as regras permanecem as mesmas ou existe algo mais específico para o comportamento no ambiente.

Comment: Geralmente tem uma estrela de prata no lado direto chat, essa parece ser a mais importante.

Comment: A estrela de prata acabou de aparecer lá de novo.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wfsf06pp/

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert que tal uma resposta com essas ideias?

Comment: @Sergio não sei se caberia com uma resposta, pois são de analises feitas por participação no chat, isso quer disser que são voláteis, e também não quer disser que sejam so essas. Fora que se alguém deve dar a resposta é o CiganoMorrisonMendez, 4/5 são dele. Não quero tomar credito indevido :D

Comment: Posso até escrever as regras sobre a minha ótica, mas isso não é garantia de que vão ficar aqui muito tempo, até porque não concordo com muita coisa sobre a administração do chat.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez acho que devias escrever uma resposta.

Comment: Acredito que discutir de forma saudável não tem problema. Cada um merece expor seu ponto de vista. @CiganoMorrisonMendez você gostaria dizer o que exatamente você não concorda sobre a administração do chat? Talvez sua opinião possa ser avaliada e você receba algum apoio, ou não. Gosto muito quando você fala sobre seu ponto de vista. Talvez seja importante não só pra mim, mas para toda a comunidade sabermos o que pode ser melhorado.

Comment: Pensei no seguinte: "É algo que você falaria/mostraria pra sua mãe, chefe ou filho? Se responder *não* pra algum deles, melhor pensar duas vezes antes de clicar <enviar>..."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Coincidentemente, a rede toda vem tendo problemas com chat nos últimos meses. Felizmente, esse não é o caso na grande maioria das salas. São apenas casos isolados, mas qualquer comunidade é tão saudável e construtiva quanto o pior comportamento dos seus membros.

Queremos que nossos sites, **incluindo o chat**, sejam lugares onde todos podem participar livremente, e ninguém vá se sentir excluído ou diminuído por outros. Se isso acontecer, vamos sempre proteger o bem-estar de quem se sentir atingido.

Recentemente o [Shog9](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6/shog9) escreveu sobre isso no [Meta SciFi SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7518/16777), e esclareceu nossa visão sobre o chat. O post é excelente, e acho melhor reproduzi-lo aqui do que escrever algo novo:

### A natureza do terceiro espaço

O chat existe para complementar o site principal. Isso é fácil de ver; Nós não *vendemos* o chat, ele não tem propagandas e sequer é possível participar sem ser usuário de um dos sites. O chat existe unicamente como um [terceiro espaço](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/do-trilogy-sites-need-a-third-place/), onde todos que visitam o SOpt podem bater papo e se conhecer melhor:

> Terceiros espaços são lugares onde as pessoas podem se reunir informalmente. O termo 'terceiro espaço' vem da ideia de que nossas casas são o 'primeiro espaço' e o trabalho é o 'segundo'
> -- *Ray Oldenburg*, sociólogo urbano

Essa definição é importante. Qualquer um consegue entender que o chat é um local público (qualquer um pode participar, todos podem ler as conversas), mas ainda assim ocorrem casos em que as pessoas parecem se esquecer de que **elas estão, sim, conversando *em público***.

### Conversas públicas e privadas

As regras de etiqueta para conversas públicas e privadas são diferentes. Se eu te convidar para jantar na minha casa, você pode ir embora se eu te deixar desconfortável, ou eu posso te enxotar se você me desrespeitar... Mas se nós estivermos sentados num bar, esperando nossa bebida, nenhum de nós vai querer ir embora, mesmo que nossa conversa comece a se tornar desagradável. É por isso que evitamos tocar em assuntos inflamatórios em público, ou insistir em um assunto mesmo depois de alguém expressar algum desconforto sobre ele.

Todos que participam do [Estouro de Pilha](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) tem em comum um interesse em programação. Mas todos também tem visões *completamente diferentes* sobre assuntos fora dessa área. Seria uma tremenda ingenuidade esperar que todos no chat tenham as mesmas opiniões sobre política, religião, arte, filosofia ou direitos humanos. Só porque alguém adora AngularJS tanto quanto você, não significa que vocês vão ter a mesma opinião à respeito das reuniões do G7.

Você não ia querer que a pessoa do seu lado no bar deixasse de comer seu hambúrguer por causa da conversa, então não há motivo para tornar o ambiente igualmente desconfortável para alguém que só queria conversar sobre Ruby on Rails. Mas, ainda assim, isso continua acontecendo.

### Respeite a todos

Quando você está num local público, em um grupo diverso, é praticamente impossível saber o que vai desagradar alguém. Se você se importa com o bem-estar de todos, a melhor coisa a fazer é ficar atento aos sinais de que alguém está se sentindo desconfortável e, quando isso acontecer, mude de assunto. Deixa a conversa para lá, ou vá para outro lugar continuar o assunto.

Entretanto, há alguns assuntos em que é possível *prever* que vão haver problemas. Se você está conversando sobre algo que levou milhares de pessoas a marcharem em protesto na vida real, pode ter certeza de que os ânimos irão se inflamar na internet também.

Da mesma maneira, se você ficou sabendo que alguma coisa - uma imagem, ou frase - incomoda um grupo de pessoas, pode ter certeza absoluta que se você postar no chat as pessoas lá também vão se sentir incomodadas.

Se você sabe que um assunto pode causar alguma reação negativa em alguém, *é desrespeitoso trazê-lo à tona no chat*. Se você toca em algum assunto que sabe que pode dividir opiniões, e depois faz questão de debater com quem discorda de você... então você está apenas [trollando](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troll_(internet)), demonstrando completa falta de respeito por todos que estão no mesmo espaço que você. Tentar conseguir um passe livre, dizendo que não sabia que o assunto era inflamatório, só vai funcionar uma vez. Você pode até ter crescido numa cidade pequena, num país pequeno, de cultura bastante uniforme, mas aqui é a internet - aprenda a respeitar a diversidade de opiniões e aprenda com ela.

`[removido um trecho que era bastante específico do que aconteceu no SciFi]`

Casos assim fazem mal à comunidade, mas em especial a todos que queriam apenas sentar e conversar sobre seus interesses com outras pessoas. Não é divertido, e é completamente possível evitar que isso aconteça.

### O que VOCÊ pode fazer

Todos os participantes do chat podem ajudar a evitar problemas assim. Eis algumas sugestões:

1. **Respeite os outros.** Vocês não precisam concordar em tudo, então se querem continuar convivendo juntos, você precisa respeitar o direito dos outros de pensar diferente. Não deixe ninguém desconfortável de propósito.
2. [Seja Respeitoso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). As regras do site valem da mesma maneira para o chat.
3. Se perceber que alguém está se sentindo mal sobre um assunto, faça algo. Sugira uma mudança de assunto, ou de sala.
4. **Respeite quando alguém expressar desconforto.** Se você sabe que alguém se sentiu afetado com a assunto, continuar discutindo é como um tapa na cara. Tenha respeito pelos outros (#1) e pare de machucá-los de propósito.

Sejam gentis e divirtam-se.