# O que fazer com o chat?

Tags: debate, chat

<kbd>**Nota**</kbd> Essa discussão começou no [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270587), motivada por alguns problemas recorrentes no chat, da rede toda. Alguns casos são **bem** mais extremos que qualquer coisa que já aconteceu por aqui, mas isso não quer dizer que nunca tivemos nossa cota de problemas.

Nós tivemos o [mesmo debate](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4588) recentemente e muitos de vocês tem muito a contribuir para a discussão. Acho que podemos aproveitar a oportunidade para participar dessa discussão maior, que envolve toda a rede.
O que acham?

---

### TL;DR: O Problema

As seguintes coisas acontecem no chat com frequência considerável:

1. **Espanto quando mensagens vulgares são sinalizadas.** O tipo de linguagem que invariavelmente seria removida do site principal, se estivesse num comentário, volta e meia é sinalizada e removida no chat. E todo mundo fica confuso.
2. **Tópicos polêmicos, que dão em confusão e ofensas.** Alguns assuntos mais controversos são trazidos à tona numa sala dedicada a falar de *outras coisas*. A discórdia acaba em ressentimento e raiva.
3. **Moderadores tentam resolver casos 1 e 2.** Mas quem decidiu que eles mandam no chat? A indignação aflora.

Esses são problemas inerentes à vida em comunidade e o primeiro passo para tentar resolvê-los é melhorar a comunicação entre todos. Então acho que nós devemos tentar **reescrever o [FAQ do Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq), para tentar esclarecer PARA QUE serve o chat, e COMO ele pode ser usado de maneira construtiva.**

Essas são as minhas observações sobre o assunto...

### Contexto

Nos últimos cinco anos o chat tem sido o "filho bastardo" do Stack Overflow e Stack Exchange: não é essencial para o modelo de perguntas & respostas mas, para muitos, é parte importante da sua rotina no site.

Ao longo desse tempo o chat passou a significar coisas diferentes para pessoas diferentes. Cada usuário regular do chat lida com ele de uma maneira diferente, e as pessoas que *não* o usam regularmente, também tem uma impressão pessoal de como ele funciona. E isso vem causando problemas.

A [ideia original do Jeff](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/do-trilogy-sites-need-a-third-place/)<sup>1</sup> era de que o chat funcionasse como um "[terceiro espaço](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_place)"<sup>2</sup>:

> Acho que um chat web em tempo real, como o Campfire, poderia servir como esse terceiro espaço, para contato informal -- Um lugar onde pessoas que se interessam pelo assunto poderiam se encontrar, conversas e colaborar entre si de maneiras diferentes. Alimentaria o senso de comunidade, sendo complementar à objetividade do site principal e ao debate não tão aberto do Meta.

Essa é, essencialmente, a "*planta*" do chat. O motivo dele existir, e a definição do que ele deveria se tornar. Diversas metáforas já foram usadas para descrever o chat: *o bebedouro* (onde você conversa informalmente sobre o trabalho), *a taverna* (onde você conversa *depois* do trabalho), etc. Essas analogias não são perfeitas. Elas não representam fielmente todas as características do chat: o bebedouro do trabalho não tem 20 pessoas em volta dele, e ninguém conversa com *todo mundo* quando chega no bar e nem espera que todo mundo te dê ouvidos e responda a tudo que você falou. Mas essas são situações comuns no chat. E são essas diferenças as responsáveis pelos problemas que eu citei lá em cima. Então não adianta tentar comparar o chat a algum lugar *real*.

Eu acredito que os problemas que ocorrem no chat raramente tem a ver com o assunto debatido, ou a linguagem utilizada, mesmo que constantemente esse pareça ser o caso. Para mim, **o problema do chat é quando seus participantes esperam que todos os presentes se comportem de uma maneira que não condiz com a realidade tanto do *sistema* quanto da comunidade em geral.** Ninguém fica dando murro em ponta de faca porque acha que a faca vai sair da frente, mas sim porque acredita que a faca não existe.

### Qual o modelo de chat do Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange

Esses são os fatos, incontestáveis:

1. **Chat não é IRC:** Por definição, todas as conversas são permanentes, públicas e associadas ao seu perfil no site principal.
2. **Chat é moderado pelos usuários:** Moderadores, usuários com privilégios e quem sinaliza, todos participam da decisão do que é - ou não - aceito no chat.
3. **Chat é moderado:** Não existe nenhuma sala onde "vale tudo". As ferramentas de moderação valem para todas as salas.

Esses fatos tem a ver com coisas que podem não ser tão óbvias:

4. **Chat não é temporário:** Tudo que você disser bêbado de madrugada ainda vai existir, em público e sob o seu nome, na manhã seguinte.
5. **Chat não está separado do site:** Você precisa participar dos sites de P&R para poder participar do chat. É no site principal que seu direito é garantido, mas é lá que ele pode ser revogado também.
6. **Você não tem controle sobre quem lê suas mensagens:** os registros são públicos e abertos a qualquer pessoa, mesmo que não está visível no chat. *Mesmo quem não é membro do site principal*. Seu chefe, seu cônjuge, seu inimigo mortal, aquele chato que estudou com você no primário... Todos eles podem ler tudo que você já falou, mesmo depois de anos.

Todas essas características tornam nosso chat um ótimo lugar para complementar o dia-a-dia do site principal... Mas *também* significam que ele não serve para muitas outras coisas, *inclusive algumas que outros sistemas de chat podem atender*! Eu acredito ser essencial que esses fatores estejam claros em toda orientação passada a todos os usuários do chat, evitando que alguém tente usar o chat para algo que ele não feito para atender.

### Explicando a natureza do chat

Como eu disse, minha idéia é reescrever a orientação dada aos usuários do chat, e alguns dos meus colegas de trabalho já estão trabalhando nisso. Mas qualquer guia precisa ser pautado num consenso sobre a *natureza* e o *propósito* do chat e é pra isso que estamos aqui.
Eu já disse o que eu acho... O que vocês acham que falta?

*Além disso, existem diversos problemas técnicos com o sistema de sinalizações e controle de salas no chat que estão sendo debatidos no Meta Stack Exchange*

---

1. [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) é um dos fundadores do Stack Overflow
2. O conceito de "terceiro espaço" foi descrito em [outro post:](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4589)

   > Terceiros espaços são lugares onde as pessoas podem se reunir informalmente. O termo 'terceiro espaço' vem da ideia de que nossas casas são o 'primeiro espaço' e o trabalho é o 'segundo'
   >
   > - *Ray Oldenburg, sociólogo urbano*

---

### Atualização

Eu estava escrevendo num comentário, mas ficou grande demais e acho que vale como atualização do post já que tem a ver com o *escopo* do que estamos discutindo. Serve como um guia adicional para a conversa.

A sugestão do @DanielGomes, de que muitos dos problemas do chat se dão por causa da permanência das mensagens e que, portanto, tornar o chat transiente (ao invés de guardar todos os logs) ajudaria a contornar alguns dos problemas faz sentido. Tornaria o chat um pouco mais privado, e isso certamente diminuiria o número de ocorrências problemáticas.

Isso também foi sugerido no MSE, e o Shog9 [comentou a respeito](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270587/toward-a-philosophy-of-chat/270865#comment877865_270865) - de maneira bem similar à minha:

> Tornar o chat privado/transiente é fora de cogitação. Nosso sistema foi criado para ser público e persistente justamente por conta dos problemas que tivemos para moderar o canal semi-oficial no IRC. Quem se incomodar com isso pode procurar outro chat.

Ser permanente é característica fundamental do nosso chat. Ela permite que tenhamos diversas outras funcionalidades usadas por todo mundo (como poder responder a uma mensagem específica), e *também* permite que o chat possa ser moderado de maneira adequada, e que as pessoas responsáveis pelas salas tenham como entender o contexto de qualquer confusão que venha a acontecer.

E, lembrando também, que o problema é que precisamos garantir o bom-convívio entre todos que participam do chat. Ter uma sala "vale tudo", mesmo que fosse transiente, onde o "mau-convívio" acontece mas depois some, não é o nosso objetivo. Não é o tipo de coisa que queremos na rede.

Além disso, o problema não é a conversa paralela num chat sobre programação. Há liberdade para se conversar sobre outras coisas - e é algo que acontece no Estouro de Pilha quase todo dia, sem problema nenhum - e se as conversas de outros assuntos um dia dominarem o chat, outras salas podem ser criadas (para música, esporte, etc, etc). Mas elas **também** serão persistentes e públicas. E **também** terão que aderir às regras de bom convívio.

Resumindo, ser persistente não torna nosso chat mais ou menos perfeito que o resto. Mas é assim que ele é, e mudar isso não faz parte da discussão por diversos motivos.

Comment: Interessante - alguns problemas que você cita, parecem girar em torno do fato de que o que é dito no chat é permanente. De quem foi, afinal, a idéia de manter o chat permanentemente? Era para "forçar" as pessoas a se comportarem? ;)

Comment: @DanielGomes Tudo que você fala no site principal, no Meta, no Twitter, no Facebook, nos comentários de algum site, também é permanente, e em alguns casos obrigatoriamente público (assim como nosso chat). Isso não é feito com o intuito de forçar qualquer comportamento, mas sim porque um chat não-persistente não teria tanta utilidade como base de conhecimento.

Comment: E você acha que o chat está servindo mesmo como base de conhecimento? Quem faz buscas no chat? Ele é pesquisável? Nenhuma das soluções que eu encontrei no Stack Exchange através do google apontaram para dentro do chat - por isso pergunto. Talvez este seja um bom tópico a ser discutido.

Comment: @DanielGomes Poder entrar no chat e obter contexto imediato do que vem sendo conversado; Poder acompanhar qualquer assunto desde o início; Poder voltar para buscar *aquele link* que alguém te enviou semana passada; Poder guardar uma mensagem para refência futura; Poder ser "pingado" por alguém e só ver a notificação 2 dias depois; Todas são funcionalidades que só existem porque o chat é permanente. Torná-lo transiente apresenta, rigorosamente, nenhuma vantagem...

Comment: Ao contrário do Daniel, eu já aprendi muita coisa no chat. Lá é um bom lugar para você fazer as perguntas sobre programação que fogem do contexto do SOpt. Por exemplo, lá é um espaço livre para você pedir referência de alguma ferramenta/plugin/etc, fazer perguntas opinativas e algumas outras coisas mais.

Comment: Eu entendo o que o Daneil quer dizer, 80% do que se diz lá é jogar conversa fora, então ele acha que esse tipo de de coisa deveria ser descartado, aí teria mais liberdade. Os 10% que é útil poderia ficar permanente. Eu sei que não é fácil operacionalizar, poderia ser algo comunitário, mas considerando que a maior parte das estrelinhas são de banalidades também, não sei se funcionaria. Mas é uma ideia p/ ser pensada.

Comment: Eu sempre pensei que a principal finalidade do chat era esclarecer dúvidas a respeito do site em si, eu mesmo sempre vou lá quando tenho alguma dúvida sobre o site, desde o manuseio ou até pra reportar algo que achei errado.

Comment: Talvez ter mais salas "oficiais" um como meta, outro como programação e outro pra jogar conversa fora, e ter ferramentas de migração pode ajudar. Pode não ser perfeito, mas ajudaria. No que pode jogar conversa fora, não seria permanente e teria mais liberdade. Os outros problemas, podem ser resolvidos, é só pensar. Em última análise, o chat de jogar conversa fora não deveria existir porque ele não complementa o principal, ele começa ser rede social. Não sou radical quanto a isso, mas estritamente falando, ele é desnecessário para o objetivo do site.

Comment: Sei que muita gente discorda, mas se o chat desaparecesse, eu não ia sentir muita falta não...

Comment: @bigown e os 10% que não são nem úteis nem conversa jogada fora, como ficam?

Comment: @bfavaretto você não para lá mesmo ;)

Comment: @Math o debate está pra decidir isso :P

Comment: Eu acho que pra conversa informal, se as pessoas não gostam das regras, tem que procurar outros lugares por conta própria, a exemplo do [#SOptMesaDeBar](https://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=SOPtMesaDeBar) fundado pelo @JorgeB. Se é pra usar o que a rede dispõe, as regras são definidas pela rede, nada mais lógico.

Comment: Mesmo que exita os "10% útil", depois de muitas mensagens ela fica no "limbo" e nem quem mandou talvez se lembre e mesmo com o "star" elas somem do destaque conforme novas com "star" aparecem. Acho que tudo lá deveria ser "temporário". Já conversas marcadas com `@` devem ficar até a pessoa ler. Se quer tornar o assunto relevante mesmo, devemos ir até o site principal :)

Comment: Exatamente, em salas segmentadas com escopo específico dá para ter algo útil e ficar permanente, em uma sala geral não tem porque ser permanente. Se é só para fazer um social eu acho que deveria fazer fora mesmo. Só vejo estas duas soluções possíveis para estes casos, deixa de ser permanente ou deixa de existir salas sociais. Qualquer outra utópica.

Comment: @bigown Criar uma sala não persistente e imaginar que ela não vai criar problemas é igualmente utópico. Como o Shog disse no comentário dele, nosso modelo de chat é derivado *justamente* dos problemas que ocorreram com a sala de IRC. Nosso objetivo não é encontrar uma solução que vai impedir que problemas aconteçam, mas sim esclarecer qual o tipo de comportamento indesejado e como todos nós devemos lidar com esses casos.

Comment: Eu não disse que não criará problemas, só que eles desaparecem

Comment: @bigown Eles também desaparecem num chat moderado! :D Mas, no final das contas, se um problema acontecer num chat transiente, eles **ainda aconteceram**. As pessoas lá no momento continuaram sendo afetadas, e a moderação ainda é necessária. Não há nada num chat transiente que signifique menos trabalho de moderação, seja dos CMs, moderadores ou usuários.

Comment: Os problemas sempre aconteceram, mesmo em um chat moderado. Eles podem desaparecer sem precisar de intervenção, de stress, nada disto. Sendo permanente ou temporário as pessoas sempre serão afetadas no momento quando isto acontece. Na verdade quase sempre os problemas não são nesse sentido, é as pessoas falarem algo que só se tornará problema porque ficará permanente. A solução é simples, mas não quer deixa como está. Eu não sabia que não era um debate de fato, por isso dei minha opinião. Se tá bom assim, então continue assim.

Comment: @bigown **É** um debate. É um debate sobre como reescrever o guia de uso do chat para maximizar a boa convivência de todos. Não é para evitar todos os problemas, mas sim garantir que eles sejam resolvidos rápida e efetivamente, e que todos tenham uma noção muito mais clara de qual o papel do nosso chat. O ponto é justamente que *não tá bom assim*, e que providências precisam ser tomadas para que as últimas confusões que ocorreram no chat da rede não voltem a acontecer. Vocês são a comunidade, e qualquer guia assim só tem a ganhar com a participação de vocês.

Answer (score 3):

## A Solução

Como já sabem o chat do site tem regras e se quiserem falar de programação e até ter uma conversa banal mas respeitadora das regras tudo bem.

Se quiserem javardar, falar de assuntos polémicos como religião, sexualidade, etc, podem sempre usar o chat não oficial do SOpt no IRC **#SOptMesaDeBar**.

Para quem não tiver cliente de IRC pode sempre aceder ao chat online:

[#SOptMesaDeBar](https://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=SOPtMesaDeBar)

Comment: Javardar é conversar sobre Java? :P

Comment: @bfavaretto ahahahah piada com duplo sentido :D

Comment: Nada contra, mas essa não é uma *solução* para o problema. Nós queremos a ajuda de vocês para chegar num novo guia de uso do chat, com regras mais claras e das quais todos tenham ciência. É isso que estamos tentando discutir.

Comment: @Gabe as regras estão bem explícitas. Podemos falar de tudo desde que não ultapassemos a velha máxima de "a minha liberdade acaba quando começa a tua". A maioria dos problemas acontece porque a maioria das pessoas no chat tem o mesmo credo, sexo, etc. E quando estrapolamos podemos ofender as ideologias dos outros. Além disso as vezes esquecemos que estamos num chat público do stack overflow, dada a à vontade  que vamos tendo. A solução passa por ter um chat mais do tipo do IRC pra conversas de bar e o chat do stack overflow com as regras atuais.